# Sharing View Model instance in different collections

Tags: vb.net, mvvm

Are there best practices for creating and sharing a View Model instance between different collection objects? For example, here's a scenario of `School` and `Class` classes that both have collections of `Student` objects:

```
Public Class Student
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Id As Integer
End Class

Public Class [Class]
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Students As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Student)

    Public Event StudentAdded(sender As Object, e As StudentEventArgs)

    Public Sub AddStudent(student As Student)
        If Not Students.ContainsKey(student.Id) Then
            Students.Add(student.Id, student)
            RaiseEvent StudentAdded(Me, New StudentEventArgs(student))
        End If
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class School

    Public Property Classes As New Dictionary(Of Integer, [Class])
    Public Property Students As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Student)

    Public Event ClassAdded(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Public Event StudentAdded(sender As Object, e As StudentEventArgs)

    Public Sub AddClass([class] As [Class])
        If Not Classes.ContainsKey([class].Id) Then
            Classes.Add([class].Id, [class])
            RaiseEvent ClassAdded(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddStudent(student As Student)
        If Not Students.ContainsKey(student.Id) Then
            Students.Add(student.Id, student)
            RaiseEvent StudentAdded(Me, New StudentEventArgs(student))
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
Public Class StudentEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property Student As Student

    Public Sub New(student As Student)
        Me.Student = student
    End Sub

End Class
```

When creating a View Model for `School` and `Class`, both could end up creating View Models for the same `Student` objects:

```
Public Class SchoolViewModel
    Inherits BaseViewModel

    Private WithEvents _school As School

    Public Sub New(school As School)
        _school = school
    End Sub

    Public Property Students As New ObservableCollection(Of StudentViewModel)
    Public Property Classes As New ObservableCollection(Of ClassViewModel)

    Private Sub _school_StudentAdded(sender As Object, e As StudentEventArgs) Handles _school.StudentAdded
        ' Create a new View Model for the Student
        Students.Add(New StudentViewModel(e.Student))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ClassViewModel
    Inherits BaseViewModel

    Private WithEvents _class As [Class]

    Public Sub New([class] As [Class])
        _class = [class]
    End Sub

    Public Property Students As New ObservableCollection(Of StudentViewModel)

    Private Sub _class_StudentAdded(sender As Object, e As StudentEventArgs) Handles _class.StudentAdded
        ' Create a new View Model or try to get the one created by the SchoolViewModel?
        Students.Add(New StudentViewModel(e.Student))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class StudentViewModel
    Inherits BaseViewModel

    Private _student As Student

    Public Sub New(student As Student)
        _student = student
        With _student
            Me.FirstName = .FirstName
            Me.LastName = .LastName
            Me.Id = .Id
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Id As Integer

End Class
```

My question is regarding the creation of `StudentViewModel` instances in both `SchoolViewModel` and `ClassViewModel` `StudentAdded` event handlers. Let's assume that the students are first added to the `School` and then assigned to their classes. The `StudentViewModel` is pretty simple and creating duplicates might not be a problem but it nonetheless seems wasteful when a View Model for the same student has already been created in the `SchoolViewModel`.

If I want to share the `SchoolViewModel`'s `StudentViewModel`, what's a best practices approach for that?

1. Passing a reference to `SchoolViewModel`'s `Students` ObservableCollection when creating a new `ClassViewModel`?
2. Creating some `GetStudentViewModelDelegate` function?
3. Creating a `Shared` collection of `StudentViewModel`?

I usually try to limit references between objects and creating new View Models would be a tradeoff for that in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't help specifically in VB, but you may be best looking into GENERICS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types

It is a way to create more of a top-level class where the internal operations represent a given "type".  Ex: Student, School, Subject (instead of a Class type named [Class].  I just see ALL types of confusion downstream.

The article covers some basics, but I think is what you are looking for.  You would want the context of things and functions generic too, so no matter what "type" you want, you can nest common functionality.

For example, for each of your student, class, school, you have an "AddStudent", "AddClass", "AddSchool", or similar.  If you have a generic with an "Add" method, then it would have the "Add" place-holder / operations once.  Then, if you have this ViewModel working as type "Student", and another of "School" that HAS an instance of ViewModel "Student", you could do something like

```
SchoolObject.StudentObject.Add()
vs
SchoolObject.Add()
```

The "Of" type can also be declared as a class type that qualifies based on an "Interface" or some parentClassType too.  So, if you have a base-class that is common to all Student, Class (Subject), School, then you can generic apply to the INTERFACE.  So, please forgive my basic capacities at VB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/interfaces/walkthrough-creating-and-implementing-interfaces

Hopefully this may help you in utilizing a concept to better fit your need that you just were not familiar with.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The main concern of my question is about avoiding creating multiple instances of the same ViewModel for a given object (Student in this case). If there's a DRapp `Student` object that exists in the School and 5 Classes, how do I avoid creating 6 instances of the StudentViewModel class? (one for `SchoolViewModel.Students` and 5 for each `ClassViewModel`'s `Students`)?